# How to split any of Macro value in post buid events

Tags: c#

I want to split the value of **`$(SolutionDir)`** in post build events in vs.
My **`$(SolutionDir)`** value is copy

```
C:\PrakashSourceCode\Source\Lancet.Engine
```

I want to change it to **`$(SolutionDir)`** value to

```
C:\PrakashSourceCode\Source\
```

so how to write the command line for the same as i don,t want to hardcore the path.

Comment: You don't want to *change* `$(SolutionDir)` that would break *everything*.  How about `$(SolutionDir)\..` ?

Comment: I don't understand your question. What do you want - exactly?

Comment: Thnks Jonathon It worked

Comment: @JonathonReinhart I think you should post the Answer.

Comment: I've posted an answer explaining the information from the comment. This way, it can be accepted if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(SolutionDir)` cannot change - it is part of the Visual Studio build system and always points to the solution directory (which is usually the top directory of a Visual Studio solution/project hierarchy.)

It seems that you want to reference the parent directory of `$(SolutionDir)`.  In that case, simply use `$(SolutionDir)\..` to traverse up one directory.